# Error in changing label values

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following piece of code ( generated from the jquery datatables plugin)

```
<div class="dataTables_filter" id="DataTables_Table_0_filter">
<label>Search: 
<input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0">
</label>
</div>
```

I want to manipulate the label text and have written the following piece of code ,could someone point out where I am going wrong .

```
$("#DataTables_Table_0_filter").closest("label").html("filter");
```

Comment: `.closest` looks for parents.  You want `.find` or `.find().first()`

Comment: I just logged in after 2 hours and the question is still present in the question stream. Could you just accept one of the answers below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That'll not work. [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) looks up the hierarchy of DOM elements. You can use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) as in the following code:

```
$("#DataTables_Table_0_filter").find("label").html("filter");
```

This will however remove the `<input>` element from within the `<label>` as well. You'll have to add the code for the `<input>` element to the string passed to the `html()` function.

Comment: You should also add a link to the .find jQuery documentation page for anyone else who finds this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `$("#DataTables_Table_0_filter").find("label").html("filter");`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) as `label` is inside `div`

you can do this way -

`$("#DataTables_Table_0_filter label").html("filter");`

or if you have multiple label's and want to access first one -

`$("#DataTables_Table_0_filter label:first").html("filter");`